# Including d3 graph in Angular 4 application

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, d3.js, npm

I am building an Angular application with typescript, where I would like to display the force directed network graph from Mike Boston build with d3 shown [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

I have copied and translated most of the code to type script without trouble but the line

```
. force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
```

fails with the error `{} has no property id`.

Only the following lines referring to d.source.x works fine?

I have installed d3 with npm and also types/d3 but still no luck, even though the typings.d.ts has an interface defining the id.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example given at http://plnkr.co/edit/qcESHb3cCwD6NZL1yuhX?p=preview helped me, with focus on code shown here:

```
this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

this.render(miserables);
```

This is the best rendition I have seen. Works for me.

Comment: I'm also using the above plunkr as reference. On top of it I've been also trying to pin the nodes on _**drangend**_. All I had to do was comment out following lines in drangend function `dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) this.simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    // d.fx = null;
    // d.fy = null;
  }` . However I'm noticing an issue where after pinning down a node, the linkDistance between parent node and the unpinned child node keeps increasing and eventually goes out of the force layout. Any idea on what's causing it or how to fix it? Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is something related to versioning, if you are using TypeScript 2.4.1, try to downgrade to 2.3.4 and give it a go.

As a workaround you could use any:

```
const forceLink: any = d3.forceLink(); 
. force("link", forceLink.id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have tried both versions with same error. Also the work around does not work for me - I think the error stems from the d.id part in the end not forceLink.

Comment: then use this:    function (d: any) { return d.id; }

Comment: even better . force("link", forceLink.id((d: any) =>  d.id ))